# How to know if the ESP8266 has been manually reset?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a code looping with the help of the `dsleep` mode. Each time `dsleep` ends, the `init.lua` is loaded, does something the goes back to sleep.

Now I want to implement a button to my ESP8266 that will trigger the reset pin. When pushed, my system should enter in a "setup mode", providing AP to do some setup (that part of code is OK).

My problem is: *How do I know if the current init was triggered manually (then go to setup mode) or by normal reboot after `dsleep`?*

I'm guessing that there should be two ways doing this:

1. **programmatically**: somehow store a meta-global variable changed by the gpio15 trigger in the end of `dsleep` ...
2. **electronically**: hack something to change one pin state when pushing reset button

Any advice?

Comment: please select the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the reboot reason by using the [`node.bootreason()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodebootreason) function.

Sample Code is (you can omit any variables after `code, reason` if you don't need the additional information:

```
code, reason, exccause, epc1, epc2, epc3, excvaddr, depc = node.bootreason()
```

Comment: Is there a definition of `exccause`? I could find code and reson, but not the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I know for a fact that it's possible (without any hacks) with the Arduino IDE with [ESP.getResetInfoPtr()](https://github.com/devicehive/esp8266-firmware/blob/master/sdk/include/user_interface.h). A guy used it [here](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=27761#p27761)

I don't think it has been enabled in nodemcu firmware.

Comment: NodeMCU does have that as pointed out in the other answer, [`node.bootreason`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodebootreason).

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is implemented by `Espressif` in their SDK:

```c
int reason = ESP.getResetInfoPtr()->reason;


switch (reason) {
    case REASON_DEFAULT_RST:
        // Normal Power up
        break;
    case REASON_WDT_RST:
        break;
    case REASON_EXCEPTION_RST:
        break;
    case REASON_SOFT_WDT_RST:
        break;
    case REASON_SOFT_RESTART:
        break;
    case REASON_DEEP_SLEEP_AWAKE:
        break;
    case REASON_EXT_SYS_RST:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```